# Pads for wire connection in KiCad

Tags: pcb, pcb-design, kicad

It's my first time making a PCB. I've got pretty far with all the YouTube tutorials however I'm now stuck on what to do next. My PCB is going to be made up of WS2812B chips (4 pin LEDs comprising VDD, GND, data in and data out).

I want to be able to daisy chain the PCBs with solid core wire however I'm not sure how to put the appropriate connection on the board in KiCad. At one end of the PCB I'll have VDD, GND and data in. At the other end of the PCB I'll have VDD, GND and data out.

What's the best way to put this onto a PCB? Presumably I'll have to edit the schematic in some way? At the moment, the first and last WS2812B chip have their respective data in and data out pins disconnected.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'd show three-pin connectors on the schematic, with an appropriate footprint (from the connector library, probably, or make your own) on the PC board - no need to actually install a connector in the resulting holes.